# eclipse tells me my project has errors, nothing is red-highlighted

Tags: android, eclipse

This happened to two programs of mine now and makes absolutely no sense. It usually comes about when I'm adding a resource file (in this case, a menu). In the package explorer:
-the project name has a small red x, indicating that there is an error in one of its files
-none of the sub-folders or files have an x or show any red highlights

None of my code has errors! Ocasionally, I see this:

```
[2010-09-02 16:09:20 - FallDown] 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.
[2010-09-02 16:09:20 - FallDown] Displaying it with 'Normal, Not Long, Landscape, Medium Density, Finger, Soft, Qwerty, Trackball, 480x320'
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually what I do in this case is to call "Project > Clean" from the menu.

With this Project > Clean we should also check our layout (xml) it might be representing any components which is going out of screen size.

Comment: After Clean Project, The problem still occur Then, I try Re-Start Eclipse. It works!

Answer (score 19):

`Window --> Show View --> Problems`. This should display a list of the specific problems that Eclipse is 'worried' about.

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse is trying to debug or run the resource xml file you have in focus. That's why it happens after you have added or edited a resource file.

To avoid the issue, make sure you debug or run your project, not the xml file.

Either select the project before you click the debug/run icon or use the debug or run dropdown and select run [your project name].

Comment: This is most relevant for beginners following the dev guide. Saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This  could help.

I had two xml layout files set up for various configurations (various layout folders according to the MMC phone operator/country where that carrier operates.

I noticed, that the message only was presented when I opened those files.  The rest of my xml's worked fine.

I am sure that it had something to do with how I did my folder configuration (not properly set by me) in the res directory.

Long story short (and I'm not saying this will fit your case) I deleted those additional configurations and it never happened again.

From what I can gather, the system couldn't deal with all those folders / configurations, so it tried to present the default one (which is what ever you have in the layout folder, and since, is trying to make it work with any device (and it can't) gives the warning and sets a configuration that understands is the one that will fit most devices.

Thing is that in my case I am dealing with phones and tablets, high and low resolutions and in some of them that setting presented an awful screen.

Here is my res folder configuration:

res
drawable
layout
**layout-mcc310
layout-mcc310-land
layout-mcc311
layout-mcc311-land
layout-mcc316
layout-mcc316-land**
values
values-es

The ones in bold were the ones with a slightly modified copy of the 2 xml file previously mentioned.

I deleted those and in my case the problem was fixed.

Cheers!

monn3t