# i got error when open xml file in eclipse

Tags: android

In Eclipse i got an error in console, When i am opening the two different name xml files(means A and B are 2 xml file. They have same data) with same data.

I got the following error in console. Why this error came.

How to handle it?

```
[2011-07-20 15:04:03 - RoadBrake] 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.

[2011-07-20 15:04:03 - RoadBrake] Displaying it with 'Locale Language ___Region __, Small Screen, Short screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, No Dock, Day time, Low Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Exposed navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 320x240' which is compatible, but will actually be displayed with another more specific version of the layout.
```

Comment: see this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630873/eclipse-tells-me-my-project-has-errors-nothing-is-red-highlighted

Comment: I am having the same problem, but my xml files are in different projects but exactly the same and having this issue. The solution in the link does not solve the issue.

Comment: Did you try the [newest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630873/eclipse-tells-me-my-project-has-errors-nothing-is-red-highlighted/7948961#7948961) answer to that question, too?

Answer (score 4):

Generally work if you use Project->Clean.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

Try to make "Project/Clean", and restart eclipse.

In my case, the problem was a "losed drawable"(Custombutton.xml+2images)

Answer (score 0):

if you have add additional jar file it may change to display this error. Please check this Properties->java Build path->Order and export make sure related .jar is marked.