# android - Meaning of the Message

Tags: android

I got the following message in my console when i run the application. What is the meaning of this message? can anybody help me.

> [2011-08-25 14:55:36 - ElGifto] 'Small Screen' is not a best match for
>   any device/locale combination.
>
> [2011-08-25 14:55:36 - ElGifto] Displaying it with 'Locale Language
>   __*Region _*, Small Screen, Short screen aspect ratio, Portrait
>   Orientation, No Dock, Day time, Low Density, Finger-based touchscreen,
>   Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Exposed navigation, No navigation, Screen
>   resolution 320x240, API Level 8' which is compatible, but will
>   actually be displayed with another more specific version of the
>   layout.

Comment: May my answer in this other question might help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630873/eclipse-tells-me-my-project-has-errors-nothing-is-red-highlighted/7948961#7948961

Answer (score 0):

Please try project clean..

```
"Project > Clean" from the menu.
```