# Why do I get this error: 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination?

Tags: android, console, locale

My project is compiled and run correctly but when I open my layout activity I get this error in console:

```
[2012-05-09 12:54:21 - order] 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.
[2012-05-09 12:54:21 - order] Displaying it with 'Locale Language ___Region __, sw800dp, w1280dp, h800dp, Extra Large Screen, Long screen aspect ratio, Landscape Orientation, Normal, Day time, Medium Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Exposed navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 1280x800' which is compatible, but will actually be displayed with another more specific version of the layout.
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Does project --> Clean... work?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630873/eclipse-tells-me-my-project-has-errors-nothing-is-red-highlighted

Comment: Can you post your folder structure in the res folder?

Comment: Happens to me when the build process gets stuck or is slow. Rebuilding/cleaning gets rid of it.