# Eclipse console errors generating 'R' error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, r.java-file

I am getting the following 2 errors on eclipse console as soon as i create a new activity

```
[2013-06-20 19:06:12 - Pingcampus] 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.
[2013-06-20 19:06:12 - Pingcampus] Displaying it with ', , Locale Language ___Region __, , sw320dp, w320dp, h533dp, Normal Screen, Long screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, High Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Hidden navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 800x480, API Level 17' which is compatible, but will actually be displayed with another more specific version of the layout.
```

This is also restricting the R.java file to be created and hence giving the error on the source code i.e.

**R cannot be resolved to a variable**

Any Help with the errors?

Screen Grab :- 
[image]

Comment: see this dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512447/why-do-i-get-this-error-default-is-not-a-best-match-for-any-device-locale-com

Comment: There's No 'SOLUTION' on that question. there's just discussion

Comment: Duplicate of [Eclipse and Android XML layouts gives "'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774686/eclipse-and-android-xml-layouts-gives-default-is-not-a-best-match-for-any-dev)

Answer (score 0):

Restart your eclipse might be solve this
or try this

`Window --> Show View --> Problems`. This should display a list of the specific problems that Eclipse is 'worried' about.

generally `clean and build` the project hope it work

Comment: Addind a screen grab above of the "Problem Console"